# I posted a canonical Q&A to a problem I solved, but now it's marked as duplicate to an older question with an incomplete solution

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I posted a question and answer using "Share your knowledge, Q&A format". This is the question - [How to integrate OpenCV into Qt Creator Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562311/how-to-integrate-opencv-into-qt-creator-android-project?noredirect=1#comment43565441_27562311)

[image]

My question was intended to be a canonical question. Since I've heard that [duplicates are not necessarily in chronological order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182868/why-is-an-older-question-marked-as-duplicate), but by usefulness, and since my answer is actually a complete how-to on how to achieve the integration of OpenCV, I wen't and marked the other questions as duplicates to my own.

However, later my own question was marked as a duplicate to one of the others. This is the reason that was stated:

> It feels a little odd to post an extremely short question (which might get closed as it's written), post an answer yourself, then go out and vote to close other questions as dupes of it. ..if anything, all of those other questions have considerably more detail to them than this one does. This should probably be closed as a duplicate of one of them, really.

But at the same time, the other question has less useful answers. It seems its virtue is that the question has more text than mine, and that it is older, according to the one who marked it as duplicate.

But I don't really think my question should be any longer, because the long parts are in the answer. My question basically states what I will solve in the answer. I thought this was how "Share your knowledge, Q&A format" was supposed to be done. Or am I mistaken?

If people came to my question from Google, would they be served better by redirecting them to an older question with a less useful answer? Or is Google searchers looking to solve their problems being served better not the goal of exact duplicates?

Comment: Just letting you know I added a tiny update to my answer here regarding your answer there.

Comment: If anyone else comes here wondering if this is legit, look at ["canonical answers for repeated questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108579/canonical-answers-for-repeated-questions), which is what the OP was doing with the Q&A.

Answer (score 10):

I'm the one who marked as duplicate. You've quoted my reasoning faithfully, and I don't feel any need to add anything to that.

Here's the issue:

First, you really can't deny your question is a duplicate of *any one* of those questions. You essentially voted exactly that, by voting them all as duplicates of yours. So, since that's solved, here's the problem:

You say the issue is the answers were not good. So... you should have posted your answer to one of them, rather than add a question that's not even really a question, and certainly not of the quality all the other ones were.

---

If you like, I am perfectly happy merging your answer into the marked duplicate. I do think you've posted an absolutely fantastic answer, and I think it'd be great there.

Comment: So, older questions can't be duplicates of newer questions?

Comment: @sashoalm older questions *can* be duplicates of new ones. However, that's not the issue here.

Comment: @ChrisF What is the issue then?

Comment: You posted a bad question, then went on a close-vote "spree" on long-since-existing questions which were of better quality than yours.

Comment: @AndrewBarber What should my question have been, then, exactly? I already know the answer, and I want to share it. I'll edit it to be to your liking.

Comment: @sashoalm it's a matter of quality, not age, see eg [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/165773) _"If the new question is a better question or has better answers, then vote to close the old one as a duplicate of the new one..."_

Comment: @sashoalm You didn't need to post a *question* at all. Just an answer. To one of the pre-existing questions.

Comment: @AndrewBarber So now that my answer is already posted, we should mislead Google searchers to inferior answers? You tell them it already has an answer, but in fact, it doesn't. Go read the other answer, it doesn't have the full steps.

Comment: @sashoalm You don't seem to be reading a single word I'm typing. I'm done.

Comment: speaking of merge to push good answer into a better question, I recall at least one case when it was done at Programmers ([crappy question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/196499/31260) / [high quality self-answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/196500/31260)). As far as I can tell, this is just what doctor ordered for cases like that

Comment: If you think the answer is fantastic, then that justifies closing other question as duplicates of sashoalm's. It's better for future visitors to see a short, to-the-point question than to see a question with lots of information that turns out to be irrelevant, with misguided attempts at solving the problem, and other clutter. @sashoalm As a general matter, you're right. Assuming your question and answer pair is better than the existing ones, yours should be the one that remains open. I can't speak for this particular case because I know nothing about the topic.

Comment: @Gilles  Hmm... That statement seems to suggest that anytime someone comes up with a great answer to a question, they should not post it to that question, but instead just post a 'better' question and their own answer to it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber When the question can be distilled down into a common issue — a frequently asked question, in the literal sense of the phrase — then yes, that's often desirable.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I can't dig it up now, but I remember the site authors asking the community not to emphasize question-ownership or internet-points. Please understand I don't care about the points (if undeserved internet-points was your concern), I just wanted to save somebody time. Posting my answer under an existing question is problematic, because it already has an accepted answer. That is actually the reason I posted my own question. With my own question, at least I can accept my answer, and there are no older questions with accumulated upvotes that would bury my post.

Comment: @Gilles I'm fairly sure I agree with you 100% on the principle you are feeling here. I'm just not really sure I agree that the questions in question count. That said, lpapp seems to agree with you there, too; as he used his De-Mjolnir to re-open the question. I'm fine with that, really. :)